# Syntax.Analysis of a sentence

Tags: grammar, syntax

Can you help me to figure out what is the function of '' no power'' in this sentence. and what does the predicate ' have ' refer to?
And what is the function of '' the setting ''? Is it predicative?

> Most people are surprised to learn that the reason they are not getting what they want in life is because their major goals are too small, and too vague, and,therefore, have no power. What really increases motivation is the setting of a large and specific power goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function of "no power" is to be the direct object of "have",  and the subject of "have" is "their major goals", by parallelism.

So we learn that "the reason ...  is because:

- their major goals are too small
- their major goals are too vague

and therefore

- their major goals have no power."

The meaning is rather unclear.  I suppose the writer means that these goals don't have the ability to change a person's behaviour.

The noun "setting" is the head of a noun phrase "the setting of a large and specific power goal".  This is the complement in the SVC sentence whose subject is "What really increases motivation".

The phrase "power goal" is not one with which I am familiar.  It might be a piece of jargon or a phrase that the author has defined earlier.